# Can I discover the values that was inputted in the form field?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Lets say we inputted the values 'abacadabra' and 'chimichanga' in the form field

The autocomplete of the browser shows these values when we start to input 'abac..' or 'chimi..'

Can I check the values that was already inputted in the form in some internal variables???

Comment: I sure hope not, and I bet many would think the same as I, and for that reason I would think that it's probably impossible. (Autocomplete can be shared across websites, after all, not sure what the conditions are exactly, maybe the `name` of the field?)

Comment: @CertainPerformance The only secure way you could do so would be to save the value in some form of cookie or local/session storage, or use server-side script to save state.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if there is a way for a website to retrieve these values, there is not.  It would be a HUGE privacy breach and vulnerability.

If you're asking if there is a way for YOU to see these in your browser, often your browser has a setting where you can see these.

For Firefox, [this Support Forum question](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/906463) leads to a plugin that allows you to edit your form history.

For Chrome, [this PC World article](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3145489/browsers/how-to-clear-unwanted-autofill-entries-in-google-chrome.html) goes step by step on how to find and delete specific entries.

1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar and select Settings
2. Click “Show advanced settings” and find the “Passwords and forms” section
3. Select Manage Autofill settings.
4. In the dialog that appears, select the entry you’d like to delete from the list. Click the “x” that appears at the end of the row.